# How to transform ( @include gradient... ) from an scss to css

Tags: css, sass

I am studying how to compile from SCSS to CSS,

I can't find a way to compile it; it's not working properly.

I tried adding it to a background and background-color it did not work

```
.tag:hover {
    background-color: rgb(83,69,91);
    @include filter-gradient(#53455b, #201d22, vertical);
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(top,  rgba(83,69,91,1) 0%,rgba(32,29,34,1) 100%));
```

All I need is for this to be written in a CSS style.

Comment: You can use `node-sass` for compile, for more info https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work.

For Multiple backgrounds!

```
.tag:hover {
    background: rgb(83,69,91);
    @include filter-gradient(#53455b, #201d22, vertical);
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(top,  rgba(83,69,91,1) 0%,rgba(32,29,34,1) 100%));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a GUI person, you could try [Scout App](https://scout-app.io/). Its a nice tool especially helpful during your learning phase.

Once you're comfortable with how Sass works, you could try using [Web Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) Visual Studio extension to automatically compile Sass files to CSS (or something similar if you're using any other IDE).